# Python: How to move a file with unicode filename to a unicode folder

Tags: python, unicode, file-manipulation

I'm having hell with moving a unicode named file between unicode named folders in a Python script under Windows...

What syntax would you use to find all files of type *.ext in a folder and move them to a relative location?

Assume files and folders are unicode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic problem is the unconverted mix between Unicode and byte strings. The solutions can be converting to a single format or avoiding the problems using some trickery. All of my solutions include the `glob` and `shutil` standard library.

For the sake of example, I have some Unicode filenames ending with `ods`, and I want to move them to the subdirectory called `א` (Hebrew Aleph, a unicode character).

#### First solution - express directory name as byte string:

```
>>> import glob
>>> import shutil
>>> files=glob.glob('*.ods')      # List of Byte string file names
>>> for file in files:
...     shutil.copy2(file, 'א')   # Byte string directory name
...
```

#### Second solution - convert the file names to Unicode:

```
>>> import glob
>>> import shutil
>>> files=glob.glob(u'*.ods')     # List of Unicode file names
>>> for file in files:
...     shutil.copy2(file, u'א')  # Unicode directory name
```

Credit to the Ezio Melotti, [Python bug list](http://bugs.python.org/issue11741).

#### Third solution - avoiding destination Unicode directory name

Although this isn't the best solution in my opinion, there is a nice trick here that's worth mentioning.

Change your directory to the destination directory using `os.getcwd()`, and then copy the files to it by referring to it as `.`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import shutil
import glob

os.chdir('א')                   # CD to the destination Unicode directory
print os.getcwd()               # DEBUG: Make sure you're in the right place
files=glob.glob('../*.ods')     # List of Byte string file names
for file in files:
        shutil.copy2(file, '.') # Copy each file
# Don't forget to go back to the original directory here, if it matters
```

#### Deeper explanation

The straightforward approach `shutil.copy2(src, dest)` fails because `shutil` concatenates a unicode with ASCII string without conversions:

```
>>> files=glob.glob('*.ods')
>>> for file in files:
...     shutil.copy2(file, u'א')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 98, in copy2
    dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 70, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 1: 
                    ordinal not in range(128)
```

As seen before, this can be avoided when using `'א'` instead of the Unicode `u'א'`

#### It this a bug?

In my opinion, this is bug, because Python cannot expect `basedir` names to be always `str`, not `unicode`. I have [reported this as an issue in the Python buglist](http://bugs.python.org/issue11741), and waiting for responses.

#### Further reading

[Python's official Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Worked - Thanks! Also +1 for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

Use Unicode string everywhere:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# source code ^^ encoding; it might be different from sys.getfilesystemencoding()
import glob
import os

srcdir = u'مصدر الدليل' # <-- unicode string
dstdir = os.path.join('..', u'κατάλογο προορισμού') # relative path
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(srcdir, u'*.ext')):
    newpath = os.path.join(dstdir, os.path.basename(path))
    os.rename(path, newpath) # move file or directory; assume the same filesystem
```

There are many subtle details in moving files; see [`shutit.copy*`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#directory-and-files-operations) functions. You could use one that is appropriate in your particular case and remove source files on success e.g., via `os.remove()`.